# get a specific div class from div and based on that do a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the title might not explain my need well. Basically, beginning of the page, I have like 20 divs, each has id of cal001, cal002 ... to cal020.

Then at the end of page, I have a bunch of divs each have class like tocal001, or tocal002. Those divs might have different classes as well. Say I have a div with class tocal001, How can I make javascript recognize the specific class that start with tocal and `clone().after()` to the cal001 div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('[id^="tocal"]').each(function(){
    var tmpid = this.id.replace('to','');
    $(this).clone().insertAfter($('[id$="' + tmpid + '"]'));
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/4TK5d/

If you want to remove the duplicates and simply "shuffle" the rows:

```
$('[id^="tocal"]').each(function(){
    var tmpid = this.id.replace('to','');
    $(this).remove().insertAfter($('[id$="' + tmpid + '"]'));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/4TK5d/1/

Comment: @Henry -- i am not sure why, my answer was just as simple, i just split it into steps for you ^_^

Comment: @Henry also this will bug out (and not work) if you have other id's on your page that **end** with the same number.

Comment: so sorry... it is really hard to choose between two equally amazing codes.

Comment: @Aliean - your code has errors. It needs to be fixed. I dont care what is chosen as the answer, i just care that it is correct.

Comment: I see no errors in the console and both fiddles work as expected. Did you downvote me? lol

Comment: @Alien -- your answer is **correct** but not optimal. **if** the OP has more than one thing that ends with the same number. the cloned div might go in the wrong place

Comment: Fair enough assumption, although provided his DOM is as described in the question, this will work just fine. Relax bro, plenty of questions still need answers.

Answer (score 5):

To get the `tocal...`:

```
var tocal = $('[id^="tocal"]');
```

To append:

```
tocal.each(function(index, item){
     var $item = $(item);
     var id = item.id;
     var num = id.substr(id.length - 3, 3);
     $item.clone().insertAfter($('#cal' + num));
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/gRhCC/

Comment: thank you so much ! If I can choose more than one checked answer I would also choose you because your answer is amazing as well!